# xilinx: Failed executing Tcl generator during memory synthesis

Tags: tcl, fpga, xilinx

I am trying to produce a memory (simple dual port ram) using core generator in xilinx 14.2. The problem is that during synthesis says :

```
ERROR:sim - Failed to run command ' -p xc3s100e-5cp132 -sd
   "C:/Users/ORiON/register_file/ipcore_dir/tmp/_cg/_dbg/" -sd
   "C:/Users/ORiON/register_file/ipcore_dir/tmp/_cg/" -dd
   "C:/Users/ORiON/register_file/ipcore_dir/tmp/_cg/_dbg/" "MEM_aRd_sWr_16x32"
   "C:/Users/ORiON/register_file/ipcore_dir/tmp/_cg/MEM_aRd_sWr_16x32.ngc"
   -intstyle xflow'. Executable file not found.
ERROR:sim - Failed executing Tcl generator.
Wrote CGP file for project 'MEM_aRd_sWr_16x32'.
Core Generator create command failed.
ERROR:sim - Failed to generate 'MEM_aRd_sWr_16x32'.  Failed executing Tcl
   generator.
```

Comment: How exactly are you calling the code to do this? (Minimal snippet please; we don't need the whole program!)

Answer (score 1):

The command itself is missing.

```
Failed to run command 'A_COMMAND_SHOULD_BE_HERE -p xc3s100e-5cp132 -sd
```

I assume it's a kind of script or makefile who is calling this command and the command is defined as a variable.  And the variable is not assigned.  Something like that?

Comment: with the ip core i try to generate a memory. i follow the instructions of the program and in the end i press generate. then everything is being automated

Comment: So you start coregen and configure and generate a core: correct?  You should have a *.cgp and a *.xco file: correct?  If you run (from the DOS prompt `coregen -p FILE.cgp -b FILE.xco` it's failing: correct?